# Convert array to string Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

didn't find the solution in SPLIT function..
i was trying to convert a string into array.. 
String is like.

```
My name-- is ery and your-- is this
```

i just want to convert that string to array, and then print it out but while getting this '-- ' break the line too.

i have did that so far

```
function listToAray(fullString, separator) {
  var fullArray = [];

  if (fullString !== undefined) {
    if (fullString.indexOf(separator) == -1) {
      fullAray.push(fullString);
    } else {
      fullArray = fullString.split(separator);
    }
  }

  return fullArray;
}
```

but is for Comma separated words in string, but what i want is to just convert string to array and then print it out while breaking line on getiing '-- ' this is array 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The question title mentions the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to work :

```
text = "My name-- is ery and your-- is this";


function listToAray(fullString, separator) {
  var fullArray = [];

  if (fullString !== undefined) {
    if (fullString.indexOf(separator) == -1) {
      fullAray.push(fullString);
    } else {
      fullArray = fullString.split(separator);
    }
  }

  return fullArray;
}


console.log(listToAray(text,"--"));
```

console output:

```
["My name", " is ery and your", " is this"]
```

what do you expect ?

Comment: In fact, you can use only `fullArray = fullString.split(separator);` inside the `if` statement because if separator is not in the string the `split` function will convert the string into an array anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method:

```
var str = "My name-- is ery and your-- is this";
var res = str.split("--");
console.log(res);

// console output will be:

["My name", " is ery and your", " is this"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing all that complicated stuff man? There is a `.split()` method that allows you to do that in a single line of code:

```
text = "My name-- is ery and your-- is this";
array = text.split('--');

> ["My name", " is ery and your", " is this"]
```

**Now if you want to break line on `--` then you can do the following:**

```
text = "My name-- is ery and your-- is this";
list = text.replace(/\-\-/g, '\n');
console.log(list);

> "My name
  is ery and your
  is this"
```